# Dynamic help menu, Ignore certain commands discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I made a dynamic help menu for my bot and I need it to ignore certain commands like the help command itself and an Info command here is the code;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const loadCommands = require('./load-commands');

module.exports = {
    commands: 'help',
    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: 0,
    callback: async (message, args, text, client, prefix) => {
        let Pepe = client.users.fetch('613817002334879747');
Pepe.then(function(result1) {
    var imgURL = result1.displayAvatarURL();
    let reply = ''
const commands = loadCommands()

for (const command of commands) {
  // Check for permissions
  let permissions = command.permission

  if (permissions) {
    let hasPermission = true
    if (typeof permissions === 'string') {
      permissions = [permissions]
    }

    for (const permission of permissions) {
      if (!message.member.hasPermission(permission)) {
        hasPermission = false
        break
      }
    }

    if (!hasPermission) {
      continue
    }
  }
        //Format the text
        const mainCommand = typeof command.commands === 'string' 
        ? command.commands 
        : command.commands[0]
        const { description } = command
        reply += `**${mainCommand}**\n${description}\n\n`
    }
    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("**Pepe's Helper**")
    .setFooter("Created by Pepe's Descendant", imgURL)
    .setDescription('Current prefix for this server is ``'+prefix+'``\nUse =info <command> to display information about the command and its usage.\n\n'+reply))
});
    },
}
```

So I need help with the part where you ignore certain commands maybe something like this;

```
if (mainCommand === 'help' || mainCommand === 'info') {
//make it ignore the commands
}
```

If you do know how to make it do this please help me out and let me know, if you do not understand my question then let me know I will explain it better for you if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [continue](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) to your if statment and it will ignore that commands

```
if (mainCommand === 'help' || mainCommand === 'info') {
 continue;
}
reply += ...
```